# Replacing old values with new values in old array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to replace my old values of an array with my new values that I get from my factorial function. I just can't wrap my head around it. I'm thinking that I might have make a new temp array

This is what I have so far:
my factorial function:

```
    public static int factorial(int n){
    if (n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

My code to print and call the function:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   int[] array = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}; 
   System.out.print("results: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    System.out.print(factorial(array[i]));
   }
```

Comment: Please correct the names in your code. Explain what values should go where.

Comment: Where did `numbers` come from?  Do you mean `array`?

Comment: `array[i] = factorial(array[i]);`?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the default values in the array {5, 4, 3, 2, 1} with the results I get from factorials.

Comment: So what values go where? What should the array look like after that's been done? Do you know how to access an element in an array?

Comment: After I get the factorials for each number in the array I want to replace that number with the factorial result. So, the replaced values in the array would be {120, 24, 6, 3, 1}. I believe that I know how to access an element in an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boann's answer is correct.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   int[] array = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
   System.out.print("results: ");
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
       array[i] = factorial(array[i]);
       System.out.print(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already changed it. Just a typo

Comment: @user3443512 Look at the _full_ answer. What are they doing with `array[i] = ...`?